# GOTO was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, dos, goto

We are trying to run a custom .BAT file that has worked fine under Win98 for years, but we just got a new server over the weekend and Win98 virtual machine does not work now apparently.  So, I'm trying to set this up so it'll work through WinXP command prompt.  What do I need to change to make this work with XP?

I type in the .BAT file and it runs fine.  It allows me to type in the date, but when I type in the date as we normally do and hit enter, I get "GOTO was unexpected at this time":

```
:CRLIST.BAT - DAILY C/R DEPOSIT LIST
:
@ECHO OFF
CALL SEARCH
CRDATE.EXE
IF EXIST DEPOS.LS DEL DEPOS.LS
CASHLIST.EXE
CALL QPR DEPOS.LS 2
```

I found GOTO in the QPR.BAT file.  Here's the code for QPR.BAT:

```
:QPR.BAT - COPY SPECIFIED LISTING FILE ( .LS) TO SPECIFIED PRINTER PORT (1-9)
:       WITH FF FOLL'G - LPTx MUST ALREADY BE CAPTURED TO DESIRED PRINTER
:
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1==" GOTO OPERR
IF "%2==" GOTO OPERR
COPY %1 LPT%2
CALL FF%2
GOTO END

:OPERR
ECHO Please re-enter this Print Queue command as follows:
ECHO        QPR  xxxxx.LS  n
ECHO.
ECHO where  xxxxx.LS  is the name of the report listing file,
ECHO  and  n  is the Network Printer No. on which to print.
:END
```

I've been reading different threads and I've tried changing `"%1=="` to `"%1"==""`, same for `%2`, and it'll then give me a new message saying:

> The system cannot find the specified file.
>   0 file(s) copied.
>   The system cannot find the specified file.
>   0 files(s) copied.

If I add `"%%1"==""`, `"%%2"==""`, and then add an extra % anywhere there is a single one, it'll display:

> The system cannot find the specified file.
>   The system cannot find the specified file.
>   0 files(s) copied.

Do I need to provide the code for anything else?  There are a lot of .BAT files so if I can get this figured out, they hopefully we can apply to the rest of the commands.

Comment: I think I solved my own problem -- downloaded DosBox from dosbox.com and problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~2"=="" GOTO OPERR
COPY "%~1" LPT%~2:
```